# Linking columns on different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, links

I'm very new to VBA coding (only dabbling for this specific project), so I would really appreciate any advice on an issue I'm having. I'm attempting to link a column range (A2:A300) on Sheet1 to a different column range (B2:B300), so that changing any of the individual cells in these ranges will change the cell in the corresponding sheet. I've experimented with different approaches (all beginning with Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)) and have been able to implement this with one cell (as in A2 on Sheet1 being linked with B2 on Sheet2), but not being able to do this for whole column ranges. I'm not doing anything fancy with the data being linked - it just needs to auto-update. Does anyone have any tips? Thank you!

Update:
I've managed to successfully link column ranges using the below on the first sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  On Error GoTo eh
  If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:B300")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Target.Row).Value = Target.Value
eh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description, , "Error in Worksheet_Change event, Sheet1"
  End If
End Sub
```

And the following for the second sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  On Error GoTo eh
  If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C2:C300")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = Target.Value
eh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description, , "Error in Worksheet_Change event, Sheet2"
  End If
End Sub
```

However, now my issue is linking Sheet3, Sheet4, etc. to different columns of Sheet1. Is it possible to modify the existing command in Sheet1 to refer to these additional sheets or would it need a separate command? Thank you!

Comment: Since you got one cell to work, you'll just need to extend your VBA to include your entire range. What would help you get more a more technical response would be if you edit your question and put in the exact code you have come up with so far.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question with my code.